# Is there any way to get the names of all the tabs in a tabstrip using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: .net, selenium, webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver (.Net) I'm able to get to a tabstip (MS Control), and I'm able to send Key events to it (Left, Right) and navigate through it.

Is there any way of obtaining the names of the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by creating your own TabStrip and Tab elements that implement IWebElement.

The first one takes an IWebDriver as a parameter to the constructor, from which it can get access to the source HTML, find (using string.IndexOf) the TabStip, convert it to an XDocument and reading all the necessary info from it.

You can then access it using a new ByEx, constructed with a new TabStrip on a specified frame.

Answer (score 0):

Let me preface that I don't know a whole lot about tabstrips.  That being said from the looks of it a tabstrip is a control in a windows form.  If that is the case then you can't access it directly from selenium.  There is a workaround though.  You can use add a reference to autoit.dll.  This allows you to interface with any windows form.  Using autoit you should be able to find an active window and get controls and parse them.